# Auth pop up returning blank page

Tags: oauth, firebase

When I submit an auth call to google to I get the popup from the google window, then when I submit my credentials and press submit it forwards on to something like

```
https://auth.firebase.com/v2/FIREBASEREF/auth/google/callback?state= etc
```

And then all I get is a blank (blue background) screen.

```
$('#loginButton').click(function() {
  myFirebaseRef.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      alert("Login Failed, please try again.")
    } else {
      console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
      myUserID = authData.uid;
    }
  });
});
```

The same is also happening when trying to auth with Github, I can press "submit" or "login" etc. and then it just loads a blank page at auth.firebase.com

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Tons of ideas. What's in the JavaScript console? Are those providers enabled in your account dashboard? Which screen is blank, the popup or the parent page? Does it actually say FIREBASEREF or does that refer to a hidden URL you don't want to share? What version of Firebase SDK? Perhaps most importantly, can you provide a repro we could run to see the error occur? A subtle error like this won't be resolved with ideas or guesses.

Comment: @Deanmv I am facing the same issues. Did you get any help ? Yes, 2nd link is working fine. Is this related to domain mismatch ?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW if anyone ends up on this issue: I was getting the exact same thing... the oauth popup was blank and not doing anything.  I fixed it by removing the async/await from my form handler:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  <button type="submit">Sign In with Google</button>
</form>
...
onSubmit = async event => {
    await this.auth.signInWithPopup(this.googleProvider)
      .then(....
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this should be an permissions issue related with the domain where you're trying to do the request like `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

In that case, Go to Firebase Console -> Authentication -> Sign-In Method then scroll down to `Authorized domains` and add your current domain from you're trying to sign in e.g. `127.0.0.1`.

Note: This is just for dev purposes, in case you want to deploy your app to Prod, you shouldn't have this configuration. For multiples environments you should check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects)

Another Note: If you're working with Javascript, you might add an `event.preventDefault()` before to call `firebase.authWithOAuthPopup(...)` to be able to obtain the result of the promise that return the `authWithOAuthPopup` function.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was adding inAppBrowser from cordova and it no longer returned blank page.