# Login to Angular progressive web app returns blank popup page

Tags: angular, authentication, manifest, identityserver4, progressive-web-apps

I'm having the following issue when converting an Angular app into a progressive web app:

When adding the app to the homescreen of my phone(through Chrome), and trying to use it, it opens the first page to allow the user to login. But when pressing the login button it should redirect to the identityServer but instead just opens a "about:blank" popup.

The login works fine when using the normal Chrome browser on my phone.

Technical info:

- Samsung galaxy S6 edge
- Android version 7.0
- Angular 5.0.1
- oidc-client: "1.3.0"
- IdentityServer 4

manifest.webmanifest:

```js
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "short_name": "MyApp",
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "description": "'Best description ever'",
  "icons": [
      {
        "src": "assets/logos/MyApp_36x36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": 0.75
      },
      {
        "src": "assets/logos/MyApp_48x48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": 1.0
      },
      {
        "src": "assets/logos/MyApp_72x72.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": 1.5
      },
      {
        "src": "assets/logos/MyApp_96x96.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": 2.0
      },
      {
        "src": "assets/logos/MyApp_144x144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": 3.0
      },
      {
        "src": "assets/logos/MyApp_192x192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": 4.0
      }
    ]
}
```

In the index.html the following is added to use the manifest:

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
```

It is worth noticing that is has been working, but no longer can get pass the login flow. Anyone got some ideas to what might be going wrong here?

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570311/google-authentication-in-firebase-showing-blank-screen-progressive-web-app). Be noted that the redirect auth does not work on PWAs (likely uses different browser instances in some cases). You can get around this by using the pop-up auth flow: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at AppAuth to manage your login flow?

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS

Jeff